# Unable to call JS function from onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a JavaScript function from the `onclick` event of two different buttons. I have dug around and searched for like problems but have not found a solutions. When I click either button I get the error

> Error: 'RemoveCode' is undefined'

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        function RemoveCode(codeType)
        {
            var selectedProjectsField = $("#SelectedProjects");
            var selectedProjectCodesField = $("#SelectedProjectCodes");
            var selectedTasksField = $("#SelectedTasks");
            var selectedTaskCodesField = $("#SelectedTaskCodes");
            var selectedOption;

            if (codeType = "Project")
            {
                selectedOption = $("#SelectedProjects :selected").index();
            }
            else
            {
                selectedOption = $("#SelectedTasks :selected").index();
            }

            alert(selectedOption);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Code for my buttons:

```
        <li>
            <label for="SelectedProjects">Selected Projects:</label>
            <select size="1" id="SelectedProjects" name="SelectedProjects" multiple></select> <button class="removeButton" onclick="RemoveCode('Project')" type="button">-</button>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="SelectedTasks">Selected Tasks:</label>
            <select size="1" multiple id="SelectedTasks" name="SelectedTasks"></select> <button class="removeButton" onclick="RemoveCode('Task')" type="button">-</button>
        </li>
```

I should note that on the same page there are multiple `change` events for the other elements on the page and they all work fine. It is just this `onclickP that is failing.

Comment: Move it out of `ready()` callback to make it global. Better use jQuery's `on()` to bind events. `$('.removeButton').click(function() {...});`

Comment: Put your function out of the $(document).ready() after that your function will be reachable.

Comment: Using onclick in the tag is not good form. Use jQuery to bind the event, as suggested by others.

Comment: Thanks all, was not aware that it being in the `ready()` event would cause problems. I moved it out as suggested and it is now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that in your `if` condition you need to use `==` (not `=`) to compare values.

To solve your issue you have two options. Firstly you could simply move the `RemoveCode` function out of the scope of the document.ready handler so that it can be accessed from the `onclick` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RemoveCode(codeType)
    {
        // your code...
    }

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        // your code...
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, it would be much better practice to add your event handlers using unobtrusive Javascript. As you're using jQuery, here's how you can do that:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $selectedProjectsField = $("#SelectedProjects");
    var $selectedProjectCodesField = $("#SelectedProjectCodes");
    var $selectedTasksField = $("#SelectedTasks");
    var $selectedTaskCodesField = $("#SelectedTaskCodes");
    var selectedOption;

    if ($(this).data('codetype') == "Project") {
      selectedOption = $selectedProjectsField.find(':selected').index();
    } else {
      selectedOption = $selectedTasksField.find(':selected').index();
    }

    alert(selectedOption);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="SelectedProjects">Selected Projects:</label>
    <select size="1" id="SelectedProjects" name="SelectedProjects" multiple></select>
    <button class="removeButton" data-codetype="Project" type="button">-</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="SelectedTasks">Selected Tasks:</label>
    <select size="1" multiple id="SelectedTasks" name="SelectedTasks"></select>
    <button class="removeButton" data-codetype="Task" type="button">-</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the advantage of adding an event handler over using onclick?

Comment: The advantage is that it follows the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) pattern. In this case it means that your HTML is entirely separate from the JS (which in turn should be entirely separate from the CSS). In practice you should be able to make an amend to any one section of the code without having to amend any other section. For example, if I change the name of a function in my JS code it shouldn't affect the HTML.

Comment: Good point, I have to move the code off to a JS file later and I think I will take that time to do clean up and SoC.

Comment: Using an event handler is also neater, and easier for other programmers to maintain. When you're in a rush to fix something, it can be fairly easy to miss an onclick attribute, but if everything is in the script block, it's more obvious.

Comment: Often you'll have a lot of elements that need to call the same code, With event binding, you can just bind them once, avoiding a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining your RemoveCode method inside a closure. This function will thus not be available as onclick callbacks of your HTML elements. 
You can just update your code to this and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function RemoveCode(codeType)
{
    var selectedProjectsField = $("#SelectedProjects");
    var selectedProjectCodesField = $("#SelectedProjectCodes");
    var selectedTasksField = $("#SelectedTasks");
    var selectedTaskCodesField = $("#SelectedTaskCodes");
    var selectedOption;

    if (codeType = "Project")
    {
        selectedOption = $("#SelectedProjects :selected").index();
    }
    else
    {
        selectedOption = $("#SelectedTasks :selected").index();
    }

    alert(selectedOption);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `ready()` method inside of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). 
You then have two approaches you can use. First is you can not use `$(document).ready()` as the buttons that call `ready()` can't be clicked until the document is ready anyway.
Second is you could bind the `onclick` inside of your `$(document).ready()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstItem').click(function() { Ready('Project'); });
  ....
});
```

Comment: Or keep it in the closure, and bind the click event in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

put your function out side of `document.ready()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () // No Need of this Function here
    {   });
        function RemoveCode(codeType) // Automatically load when Your page is getting loaded on Browser.
        {
            var selectedProjectsField = $("#SelectedProjects");
            var selectedProjectCodesField = $("#SelectedProjectCodes");
            var selectedTasksField = $("#SelectedTasks");
            var selectedTaskCodesField = $("#SelectedTaskCodes");
            var selectedOption;

            if (codeType = "Project")
            {
                selectedOption = $("#SelectedProjects :selected").index();
            }
            else
            {
                selectedOption = $("#SelectedTasks :selected").index();
            }

            alert(selectedOption);
        }


</script>
```